# receiving JSON response in java

Tags: java, php, json

I want to receive JSONArray in java but it's always giving me a null pointer exception.
I'm sending the Response with 2d array through php

Here's my php code :

```
$this->arr = array(array("Max" , 1 , true) , array("Adam" , 2 , false));
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setdata($this->arr);
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
```

and that's the code I wrote in java :

```
String link = Config.API_BASE_URL + "/" + loggedInId + "/notifications";

    GetRequest request = new GetRequest(link) {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            if (this.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                try {
                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
                    viewNotifications(json);
                    //viewNotificationsTest();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Before processing the JSON response, first check if the response is null , if not null assign it to JSONArray. The response you receive is null that's why you are getting null pointer exception

Comment: Have you checked that the server response is not malformed?